# Spring: CustomizableTraceInterceptor does not get invoked

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

My interceptor declaration looks like this:

```
<bean id="loggingInterceptor"
      class="org.springframework.aop.interceptor.CustomizableTraceInterceptor">
    <property name="enterMessage" value="Enter: $[targetClassShortName].$[methodName]($[arguments])"/>
    <property name="exitMessage" value="Exit: $[targetClassShortName].$[methodName](...) returning [$[returnValue]]"/>
</bean>
```

With Pointcuts:

```
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="loggingInterceptor"
                 pointcut="execution(public * com.mycompany.server..*.*(..))"/>
</aop:config>
```

But there are no traces from the CustomizableTraceInterceptor.

- I verified package in pointcut is correct
- I did check my logging level it's set to trace.
- I verified that spring-aop.jar is one of the maven dependencies
- Added aspectjrt and aspectjweaver to maven dependencis

I even went as far as Implementing my own intercepter that extends the CustomizableTraceInterceptor and overwrote writeToLog method, put System.out.println just to see if the class gets invoked. It doesn't.

Can someone see what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

you need to set the loggername property of the bean CustomizableTraceInterceptor.
Also make sure you set the log level as trace.

You can declare any name for the logger class - which you are writing as part of trace log4j configuration.